# How can I determine which element I clicked in a Nodelist using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a number of button with the classname "button". I am looking for a way to determine in plain javascript which button I clicked. Using jQuery I would do

```
jQuery(".button").index(this);
```

I have been trying to find a way with

```
document.querySelectorAll(".button").onclick = () =>
{
    console.log("You clicked button number" + ???);
}
```

This doesn't respond to any button, whereas `document.querySelector(".button")` only selects the first button.

Comment: You can use `this`. For that you'll need to remove the arrow function and use conventional `function(){  }`.

Comment: You need to call `addEventListner` method to attach an event to the element

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".button")` will return a nodelist. You'll need to loop over this node list and add click event listeners to each button within the nodelist. The loop will give you the index of the current button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Using onclick in JavaScript**
You can use `.forEach()` to iterate each button.
Then you can get the information from each click event.

```
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((button, index) => {
  button.onclick = (event) => {
    console.log("You clicked button number " + index);
    console.log("You clicked button with class " + event.toElement.className);
    console.log("You clicked button with text " + event.toElement.innerText);
  }
})
```

**2) Using onclick in HTML**
You can use `this` in `.onclick` function call to get the button element on click.

```
<button class="button teste" onclick="whatButton(this)">1</button>
<button class="button teste" onclick="whatButton(this)">2</button>
<button class="button teste" onclick="whatButton(this)">3</button>
```

```
function whatButton (button) {
  console.log("You clicked button with class " + button.className);
  console.log("You clicked button with text " + button.innerText);
}
```

**3) Using addEventListener**
This is similar to `.onclick`, but you can use `this` directly to target the button element.

```
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((button, index) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("You clicked button number " + index);
    console.log("You clicked button with class " + this.className);
    console.log("You clicked button with text " + this.innerText);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can determine which button is clicked

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

buttons.forEach(button => {
 button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
     console.log('Clicked on: #id-' + event.target.id);
    })
})
```

```html
<button class="button" id="1">button 1</button>
<button class="button" id="2">button 2</button>
<button class="button" id="3">button 3</button>
```

You can get any other attribute from `event.target` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop all the elements using `querySelectorAll` and attach the event to each one.

The main disadvantage of doing this, is you will be adding multiple events.  Also if elements are added later, you will have to add the events to them too.

Another option is using a delegated event, basically this is attach the event to some parent element and wait for the click there, you could attach this to the body.  You can attach to the body, but for performance reasons if you can attach to some parent element it works better.

eg..

```js
const youClicked = document.querySelector('.you-clicked');

document.querySelector('.buttons')
  .addEventListener('click',(e) => {
    //lets only look for the buttons
    //and not for this div
    if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
      youClicked.innerText = e.target.innerText;
    }
  });
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button>One</button>
  <button>Two</button>
  <button>Three</button>
  <button>Four</button>
  <button>Five</button>
  <button>Six</button>
  <button>Seven</button>
</div>

<br>
<div>
  You Clicked =>
  <span class="you-clicked">?</span>
<div>
```